Growth of the least $k$ such that $\sigma^k$ has a fixed point for each $\sigma\in S_n$
Let $f(n)$ be the least $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma^k$ has a fixed point for each permutation $\sigma\in S_n$. In light of the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$, $f(n)$ is the least $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each partition $\lambda \vdash n$, there is an $i$ with $\lambda_i\mid k$.
As far as I can tell, there is no nice formula for $f$, but some unoptimized python code gave the first 12 values as
$$1,2,3,4,10,6,28,24,36,30,132,60,…$$
which does not show up on OEIS.
I was wondering if there was a nice asymptotic for $f(n)$. Clearly $n\mid f(n)$ and $f(n)\mid \text{lcm}(1,\ldots,n)$, but these bounds are rather weak. Any literature on $f$ would also be appreciated.
EDIT: Based on the values given by @RobertIsrael, it appears that $f(n)$ is roughly $\exp(cn)$ for some $c\approx0.37$. Another thing of note is that it looks like for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there is an $N_m$ so that $m\mid f(n)$ for $n\geq N_m$. The apparent values of $N_m$ seem to be (values for $m$ prime shown in red)
$$1,\color{red}{4},\color{red}{8},19,\color{red}{14},8,\color{red}{23},37,43,...$$
What sticks out is that $N_p/p$ is close to $1/c$ for $p$ prime, while $N_m/m$ tends to be larger for $m$ a power of a prime. Since the primorial $n\#$ is roughly $\exp(n)$ by PNT, it may be possible to find an asymptotic lower bound for $f(n)$ by showing $N_p\sim p/c$ for some $c$ and then arguing $m\#\mid f(n)$ for $n\geq\max(N_2,N_3,N_5,\ldots,N_{\pi(m)})$.

Not an answer, but here are the first $50$ values:
1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6, 28, 24, 36, 30, 132, 60, 312, 210, 120, 720, 2040, 630, 2280, 1260, 840, 3960, 9660, 9240, 8400, 16380, 15120, 13860, 146160, 60060, 78120, 131040, 18480, 471240, 55440, 1392300, 1025640, 1436400, 240240, 1413720, 2273040, 22822800, 5634720, 5405400, 720720, 32515560, 33873840, 89535600, 10090080, 205405200
as computed using the following Maple code:
F:= proc(n,k) 
# does every partition of n contain a divisor of k
  option remember;
  local i;
  if k mod n <> 0 then return false fi;
  for i from 2 to n-2 do
    if k mod i <> 0 and not procname(n-i,k) 
    then return false fi;
  od;
  true
end proc: 
f:= proc(n) local k;
   for k from n by n do
     if F(n,k) then return k fi
   od
end proc:
map(f, [$1..50]);


Thanks for this. These values definitely seem to grow exponentially (more precisely, it looks like $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log f(n)/n\approx 0.37$).
